# Chrome/webview crash

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

My app crashes due to some issue with the WebView it uses. I can't figure out steps to reproduce, but this happened twice in an hour. Phone: Pixel 1, 8.1, latest updates. The app contains some native screens and a webview for Cordova pages.

I don't even understand the log. What's `google/sailfish/sailfish:8.1.0/OPM2.171019.029/4657601:user/release-keys` ?

Where is this issue coming from?

At the end of the log:

```
MY_APP_PACKAGE_NAME/MY_APP.activities.MainCordovaActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

**Log:**

```
04-10 11:42:54.467 17457 17296 F google-breakpad: V AndroidWebView:65.0.3325.109
04-10 11:42:54.467 17457 17296 F google-breakpad: O A arm64 04 aarch64 google/sailfish/sailfish:8.1.0/OPM2.171019.029/4657601:user/release-keys
04-10 11:42:54.467 17457 17296 F google-breakpad: P browser
```

...
(list of .so files) 
followed by:

```
04-10 11:42:54.614 14720 17296 F libc : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 17296 (Thread-30), pid 14720 (p.MY_APP.debug)
04-10 11:42:54.906 17461 17461 F DEBUG : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
04-10 11:42:54.906 17461 17461 F DEBUG : Build fingerprint: 'google/sailfish/sailfish:8.1.0/OPM2.171019.029/4657601:user/release-keys'
04-10 11:42:54.906 17461 17461 F DEBUG : Revision: '0'
04-10 11:42:54.906 17461 17461 F DEBUG : ABI: 'arm64'
04-10 11:42:54.906 17461 17461 F DEBUG : pid: 14720, tid: 17296, name: Thread-30 >>> MY_PACKAGE_NAME <<<
04-10 11:42:54.906 17461 17461 F DEBUG : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
04-10 11:42:54.912 17461 17461 F DEBUG : Abort message: '[FATAL:scoped_file.cc(42)] : Bad file descriptor (9)
04-10 11:42:54.912 17461 17461 F DEBUG : '
04-10 11:42:54.912 17461 17461 F DEBUG : x0 0000000000000000 x1 0000000000004390 x2 0000000000000006 x3 0000000000000008
04-10 11:42:54.912 17461 17461 F DEBUG : x4 0000000000000000 x5 0000000000000000 x6 0000000000000000 x7 7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
04-10 11:42:54.912 17461 17461 F DEBUG : x8 0000000000000083 x9 b61b19049fad6cbc x10 0000000000000000 x11 ffffffffffffffff
04-10 11:42:54.912 17461 17461 F DEBUG : x12 00000072ec51359f x13 0000000000000009 x14 0000000000000009 x15 ffffffffffffffff
04-10 11:42:54.912 17461 17461 F DEBUG : x16 0000005b7cf02fa8 x17 000000738074c430 x18 0000000000000000 x19 0000000000003980
04-10 11:42:54.912 17461 17461 F DEBUG : x20 0000000000004390 x21 0000000000000083 x22 00000073807b2768 x23 00000072ecd69000
04-10 11:42:54.912 17461 17461 F DEBUG : x24 0000000000001000 x25 00000072e3bff588 x26 00000072e3bfe761 x27 00000072e3bfe760
04-10 11:42:54.912 17461 17461 F DEBUG : x28 f4fa6f45970d41d8 x29 00000072e3bfe720 x30 00000073806ffa2c
04-10 11:42:54.912 17461 17461 F DEBUG : sp 00000072e3bfe6e0 pc 00000073806ffa4c pstate 0000000060000000
04-10 11:42:54.915 17461 17461 F DEBUG :
04-10 11:42:54.915 17461 17461 F DEBUG : backtrace:
04-10 11:42:54.916 17461 17461 F DEBUG : #00 pc 000000000001da4c /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+112)
04-10 11:42:54.916 17461 17461 F DEBUG : #1 pc 0000000000914fe4 /data/app/com.android.chrome-8K-my15EW_DcpI3Dnmj9zA==/base.apk (offset 0xb03000)
04-10 11:42:59.319 720 720 E /system/bin/tombstoned: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_01
04-10 11:42:59.380 883 1124 E InputDispatcher: channel '575d781 MY_APP_PACKAGE_NAME/MY_APP.activities.MainCordovaActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-10 11:42:59.463 883 912 E zygote64: Error encountered killing process cgroup uid 99030 pid 15394: No such file or directory
```

Comment: hi, any news on this? I have a similar problem opening a html5 date picker from the webview.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the answer. I haven't seen the error recently. We've done a lot of changes in this project, there have also been many updates of the OS and WebView, and I don't know what caused the error to go away.